# How to add video player navigation for videos in html

Tags: html, video-player

I need to add video player for my video files. Can any one help me to add? Is there any free players on web?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way ever. With **HTML5**, you can simply use the video tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<video src="movie.ogg" controls="true">
your browser does not support the video tag
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

If not on HTML5, I'd suggest using the [jQuery media plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/media/)

Comment: your syntax for controls attribute is wrong. it is controls="true"

Comment: No i tried this code is not supported for my browser. Pls can u tell me some other method?

Comment: jQuery media plugin as mentioned above is really good

Comment: Love the jQuery method, suited my needs perfectly. Send the correct markup and leave it up to the client!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing

1. HTML5

   <video src="movie.ogg" controls="true"></video>

many browser like firefox, chrome already supporting this.

2. use flash player and embed the video
3. simply use embed tag to embed an object. There is a issue here. browser needs to support this.